# Pass arguments to a generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, bluebird

I have been totally stuck at this for the last few hours.

**How to pass paramters to a generator function?**

```
function* getFoo(foo) {
    return yield Promise.resolve(foo + 10);
}

exports.testRoute = Promise.coroutine(function* (req, res) {
    let bar = yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo);  // <--- how to pass argument??
    res.send(bar.toString());
});
```

**Current Code throws Error** (and I know it points me to [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Error:-A-value-was-yielded-that-could-not-be-treated-as-a-promise) but it doesn't say anything about argument passing):

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: A value [object Promise] was yielded that could not be treated as a promise
    See http:// goo.gl/4Y4pDk
From coroutine:
    at Function.module.exports.Promise.coroutine (d:\Workspace\Github\API-NodeJS\app\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\generators.js:111:17)
```

**If I do this:**

```
let bar = yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo(5));
```

I get following Error (again self explanatory error, but [this link](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Error:-generatorFunction-must-be-a-function) doesn't explain argument passing either):

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: generatorFunction must be a function
    See http:// goo.gl/6Vqhm0
    at Function.module.exports.Promise.coroutine (d:\Workspace\Github\API-NodeJS\app\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\generators.js:107:15)
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the context but can't you just do `yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo.bind(null, 5))`?

Comment: @LINKIWI nope, I get the first error **A value [object Promise] was yielded ...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is this:

```
function* getFoo(foo) {
    return yield Promise.resolve(foo + 10);
}

exports.testRoute = Promise.coroutine(function* (req, res) {
    let bar = yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo)(50);
    res.send(bar.toString());
});
```

You need to understand what [`Promise.coroutine`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) does. It takes a generator and it returns a function which returns a promise.

As you see in the first case(`yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo);`), you are yielding the result of `Promise.coroutine` which is a function and not a promise, which results in the error:

```
A value [object Promise] was yielded that could not be treated as a promise
```

In the second case (`yield Promise.coroutine(getFoo(5));`), you are just initiating your generator. `getFoo(5)` returns a "generator" object but `Promise.coroutine` wants a "generator function", which results in: `generatorFunction must be a function`.

The fact bluebird is showing the result of Promise.coroutine as `[object Promise]` contributes a lot to the confusion, since Promise.coroutine should return a function instead, but I couldn't figure it out. I guess you could ask it as another question.

Comment: Yup, just recently figured it out. Didn't expect it to be this much simple.

Comment: Hmm, I guess It is because bluebird expects a `Promise` next to `yield` keyword *(as you can see I've wrapped my `testRouter` into `Promise.coroutine`)*